# Solve two equations with two unknowns parameters

Tags: matlab, algebra, wolframalpha

I have these two equations and I want to find the values of these two parameters:

```
9.393e(16) = ((N*K)/(K + 0.0045))*(1 - exp (-(K + 0.0045)*120))

1.376e (17) = ((N*K)/(K + 0.0045))*(1 - exp (-(K + 0.0045)*240))
```

How can I solve it in matlab or wolfram please

Answer (score 1):

I guess a hand calculator is sufficient for that.

Call:

```
a = 9.393e(16)
b = 1.376e (17)
Q = (N*K)/(K + 0.0045)
f = exp (-(K + 0.0045)*120)  => exp (-(K + 0.0045)*240) = f^2
```

You have:

```
 a = Q (1 - f)
 b = Q (1 - f^2)
```

so

```
a/b = (1 - f) / (1 - f^2) = 1 / (1 + f)
```

thus

```
f = b/a - 1
```

You can take the `log` at both sides and solve for `K`.

```
-(K + 0.0045)*120 = log(b/a - 1)
```

To find `N` the equation is again just linear.

Comment: I am really sorry, I don't understand your solution. Could you please guide me for the matlab

Comment: @HishamAlghamdi, I extended the answer. There is no need for matlab to solve that. That is not matlab code, rather hand calculations. you can use matlab to evaluate the log.

Comment: Sorry, but how can I solve it if the second equation modified to 1.376e (17) = ((N*K)/(K + 0.0045))*(1 - exp (-(K + 0.0045)*300))

Comment: I found the solution by using in Matlab:

 sym x

   x=solve('((1-exp(-(x+0.0045)*120))/(1-exp(-(x+0.0045)*280)))-0.682')

Answer (score 1):

You can solve simultaneous non-linear equations in MATLAB via `FSOLVE` or `LSQNONLIN`.  However, this requires the Optimization Toolbox.

See this [MathWorks knowledgebase article](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-15NRJ/).

Given the magnitude of the LHS of your equations, I would not be surprised if you see some numerical instability.  You might want to do this problem by hand as suggested by Acorbe.